# How do I generate random numbers in 3 lines - Linux Shell Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, random

I would like to write a code that can generate 3 rows of 6 random numbers spaced out, which shuffle after a given time (0.5 seconds), and no new rows are created, basically 6 random numbers keep generating in 3 rows.
The code I have so far is:

```
echo " "

echo " "

echo " "



for i in {1..5};

do

for i in {1..1};

do


echo -ne " $(($RANDOM % 100))   $(($RANDOM % 100))   $(($RANDOM % 100))   $(($RANDOM % 100))   $(($RANDOM % 100))   $(($RANDOM % 100))\r"


done

sleep 0.5

done
```

However, when I try to add the second and third row to this, it doesn't seem to work the way I want it. A sample output could look like:

45 88 85 90 44 22

90 56 34 55 32 45

58 99 42 10 48 98

and between these numbers, new ones will generate, keeping only 6 columns and 3 rows. I have tried making matrix too but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Store the original random numbers in an 18-element indexed array, The each time you need to redisplay shuffled, use something like `for i in $(shuf -i 0-17); do [ "$i" -gt '0' -a $((i % 3)) -eq '0' ] && printf "\n"; printf "%3d" ${array[i]}; done`

Comment: Thank you! I will give this a try. This seems like a better algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you have it finish, but continuing on from the comment, I would fill an indexed array with random values between `1-100`, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

for ((i = 0; i < 18; i++)); do      ## fill array with random values
    a[i]=$(($RANDOM % 100 + 1))
done
```

What you would then want is a function you could call, passing the number of values in each row (so you can output a `'\n'` after those digits print) and then the array values as arguments to the function to read into a local array within the function (of course, you can just use the original array without worrying about passing elements as arguments, but I prefer using `local` values within function to preserve values in other scopes unchanged. For that your print function could be something like:

```
## function to print array in shuffled order, using tput for cursor control
prnarray() {
    local n=$1
    local al=( ${@:2} )
    local c=0
    for i in $(shuf -i 0-$((${#al[@]} - 1))); do
        [ "$c" -gt '0' -a $((c % n)) -eq '0' ] && printf "\n"
        printf " %3d" "${al[i]}"
        ((c++))
    done
    printf "\n"
    tput cuu 6   ## tput is used for cursor control to move back to top
}
```

Then you really don't need much else bu a loop to print the array, `sleep` for some period of time and then call `prnarray` again to overlay the output with a new shuffle. e.g.

```
tput sc     ## save cursor position

## call prnarray 3 times with 5 sec. delay between displays
declare -i c=0
while (( c < 3 )); do
    prnarray 3 ${a[@]}
    ((c++))
    sleep 5
done

tput rc     ## restore cursor position
```

**Example Use/Output**

The array will print in the same spot every 5 seconds with the same elements shuffled to different positions within the array.

```
$ sh randomshuf.sh
  33  30  34
  86  98  48
  94  89  80
  50  57  34
  11  45  57
  80  42  22
```

Give it a shot and let me know if you have any questions.

**Note:** to make it `3x6` change the lines:

```
 tput cuu 3
```

and

```
prnarray 6 ${a[@]}
```

With those changed your output would resemble:

```
$ sh randomshuf.sh
  85   9  45  14  18  16
   6  59  43  19  29  58
   7  89  18  72  29  29
```

Comment: Hi David, this has done the trick! Thank you, and I think that in an attempt to solve the problem without making a function, I was not able to design a working algorithm for the problem. Your solution has worked. Thank you once again. I don't know how to make this the best answer as I am new to this forum, but I will explore! Thanks again

Comment: Glad I could help. I've worked with bash for close to 20 years. It is an amazingly capable shell (all shells have their individual strengths), but bash in particular provides a wide set of tools to do just about anything you need to do. Good luck with your scripting.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to avoid using the shell for this. The shell is great for automating system administration tasks - e.g interact with files, directories, shell commands -, but it is also great to keep people away from learning a 'real' and most powerful programming language.

python, ruby or perl can help you out.

**if all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail.**

e.g ruby

```
def print_random_numbers(num)
  random_numbers = []
  num.times do |n|
    random_numbers << rand(100)
  end
  puts random_numbers.join(' ')
  puts
end


while true
  3.times do
    print_random_numbers(6)
  end
  sleep 0.5
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Someone suggested Aptana as an IDE for Ruby. Would you recommend any for use in Linux?

Comment: You can use vi or RubyMine

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I really understand your problem, but:

This gets you 6 numbers taken at random from the range 1-100

```
numbers=$(shuf -i 1-100 -n 6)
echo $numbers
```

The numbers are selected without repetition. If you want repetition, use -r.

This gives you a permutation of the numbers drawn before:

```
 echo $numbers | tr ' ' '\n' | shuf | xargs echo
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for your response. What I would like to achieve is:
I should get 3 rows of 6 numbers
and after 0.5 seconds, the total of 18 numbers are regenerated
But the previous numbers are no longer shown on the screen. It is like the previous numbers are replaced with 18 new numbers that are randomly generated, and arranged in the format of 3 rows and 6 columns. In the first part of your kind response, you managed to generate 6 numbers. But how can I generate 3 rows that randomly re-generate and the previously generated numbers get replaced by the new set of numbers. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: I fear that also your new explanation is not clear to me, but from my response, you should at least see how to get any set of random numbers with or without regeneration. If you need several sets, just store them in several arrays. As for "replacing on the screen", this has nothing to do with generating the numbers and is really a (possibly complex) topic on its own, so you should make a different question out of it, i.e. "how do I replace one information by another one on the screen".

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I apologize as I am fairly new to this forum, and I will keep this in mind next time I post. Thank you for your help too!